# How to structure an nginx docker container and the build of the assets it serves

Tags: docker, nginx, webpack

I am running an nginx service inside a docker container, and it serves some static files and 1 compiled file (a js bundle build by webpack.)

I don't want my source files in the nginx container - instead I only want the files that nginx will be allowed to serve in there.

Therefore I currently have 2 docker containers - 1 that generates the .js bundle which MUST be run before the build of the second docker image - which then picks up the bundle file from the host (which was generated by the running of the 1st container.)

This seems wrong as my nginx image build should be immediately runnable from source I feel.

However if I added the webpack build into the nginx images dockerfile then I would have to copy the whole source into the container which also feels wrong.

What am I missing?

(Notes: I have considered copying the files in there, doing the build then just `rm`ing the files I don't want but it seems icky and will unnecessarily increase the size of the container. Willing to accept if this is the correct approach though!)

Comment: How are you deploying it ? Using swarm mode ?

Comment: not even got as far as working that out at the moment - I am using docker-compose to generate the images and run the containers on local and was probably going to use swarm. How come?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get what you want with the [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) feature of Dockerfile which was introduced in Docker 17.05.

What multi-stage allows you to do is produce a single Docker image by building an artifact in one container and then immediately copying that artifact into another container, all from within one Dockerfile. So in your case, it will allow you to build your webpack bundle and then copy that bundle into the nginx container, without including any of the source JS files. This removes all the hacks such as having to delete content or have a container that is over-provisioned with software e.g. your nginx Docker image doesn't need webpack installed.

So you would approach it by writing a `Dockerfile` that looks something like this (the commands are just an example, but I'm sure you can replace them with the correct one):

```
FROM node:8.5.0 as webpack
COPY /src/js /src/js
RUN webpack /src/js/app.js /app.bundle.js

FROM nginx:1.13.5
COPY --from=webpack /app.bundle.js /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The output of the above should be a lightweight nginx Docker container image that includes your webpack bundle and not much else.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thanks so much!